# How can I use the bottom sheet without changing the size of the background?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I open the `showModalBottomSheet` and click on the field to write, the background and card size are affected. How can I prevent any effect on the background?
I tried to make my app responsive, so I used the `LayoutBuilder -> constraints`

[image]

```
void test1(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      elevation: 10,
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.only(
                  top:10 ,
                  right: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10,

                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          label: Text('item name'), hintText: 'add item '),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          label: Text('amount'), hintText: 'add amount '),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('No Data chosen')) , 
                          TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('Chosen Data') , style: ButtonStyle(foregroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurpleAccent) ),) ,
                          
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: Text('add Transaction')),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        );
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Constant height to that blue `Container`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you're looking for a way
Add the following to your screen's Scaffold widget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
            body: Stack(...)
        )
    }
}
```